# made a button component in react js buts keeps throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import './button.styles.scss';

const BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES = {
  google:'google-sign-in',
  inverted:'inverted',
};

const Button = ({children, buttonType, ...otherProps}) => {
  return (
    <button 
      className={`button-container${BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES[buttonType]}`}
    >
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

but keeps getting error

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:97 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at sign-up-form.component.jsx:102.
    at SignUpForm (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:544:86)
    at div
    at SignIn
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the error and making sure you properly exported the component?

Comment: Note that your button has no text so it won't show properly when you do get it to work.

Comment: text is in another component

Comment: Provide the sign up form also

Comment: Did you import it correctly? import Button from "./path/to/your/Button"? It will give you this error if you import it like {Button}